Interpret PCA components as a predicting variable in a regression model
I'm struggling to find an answer to this question but I have used the principal components of a PCA as predictors in a regression model and I know want to interpret their effect. Let's say I ran a PCA on three variables $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$ that I standardized for this and used the first principal component ($PC_1$) as a predictor in a non-linear regression model. Let's assume as well that the correlation coefficients between $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$ and $PC_1$ are respectively 0.7, -0.6 and 0.8.
My understanding is that if $PC_1$ increases by 1, it means the standardized $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$ increase by 0.7, -0.6 and 0.8 respectively. I can then convert that back to their original scale to get an idea of the change that represents in the original units of $V_1$, $V_2$ and $V_3$. Is that correct of am I missing something ?

Yes, you're essentially correct. To be precise, if $PC_1$ increases by 1, the corresponding standardized variables $V_1^*$, $V_2^*$, and $V_3^*$ change according to their loadings in the PCA, not the correlation coefficients. The loadings are the weights used to compute $PC_1$ from $V_1$, $V_2$, and $V_3$. You can recover an interpretation from checking PC loadings. I would expect the correlation coefficient to tell you something fairly similar though.
